# PHP IDE with design view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, ide

I am looking for a PHP IDE to work with that contains a design view like ASP .NET where i can add button, tables, menus automatically. So is there an IDE like that for PHP?

Comment: Are you aware PHP is rather very rarely used for GUI creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse for PHP Developers does contain this exact thing - because it's a java desktop client though it is pretty 'clunky' but give it a whirl! http://eclipse.org

Edit --

Just realised you essentially want a drag and drop interface - You actually want a html editor with drag and drop functionality as PHP itself is just server side scripting, there's a bit of a difference between ASP.NET (as it's a framework) and PHP which is an actual scripting language. PHP generally just renders HTML elements - in which case you're actually looking for a drag and drop HTML interface. I'm loathed to say it but the only one I'm aware of that's reliable (ish!) is Dreamweaver.

Comment: Thanks for the great choices, I searched for Dreamweaver and it's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get to .NET/VB ide is having an editor with html widgets, `edit +` has this and `eclipse` also has some mode or add-on for html widgets.

Now, you need to be aware  *even if there was such an IDE* ... real men code their ui by hand.

Happy coding my friend, cheers.